# How to submit consecutive bash jobs using another job with a loop

Tags: bash, loops, jobs

I have to phase (using shapeit software) 29 chromosomes, so it would be great if a could send a job that call another, the names of the files are the same, only change the chromosome number.
Example phase.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
shapeit \
-P chr_1.ped chr_1.map \
--duohmm \
--rho 0.01 \
-O chr_1.phased
```

I would need something like another job calling it

```
#!/bin/bash
for chr 1...29 
sbatch --phase.sh 
done
```

Thank you very much

Comment: Can you clarify which part of script change?

Comment: I don't know how to do the second bash job (the for..), and in the first one, I guess that instead of "chr_1.ped chr_1.map" it should be something like "chr_*.ped chr_*.map" to indicate that it is for all the chromosomes. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you can change the first script to something like

```sh
#!/bin/bash
shapeit \
  -P "$1".ped "$1".map \
  --duohmm \
  --rho 0.01 \
  -O "$1".phased
```

and call it `sbatch` (or is that `phase.sh`?), you can then call it with

```sh
for chr in {1..29}; do
  sbatch --phase.sh "chr_$chr"
done
```

Of course, a better design might be to change the first script to run a loop over the arguments you pass it;

```sh
for chr; do
  shapeit \
    -P "$chr".ped "$chr".map \
    --duohmm \
    --rho 0.01 \
    -O "$chr".phased
done
```

and then call it like

```sh
thatscript chr_{1..29}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `phase` script can be changed on this way:

```
#!/bin/bash
shapeit \
-P $1.ped $1.map \
--duohmm \
--rho 0.01 \
-O $1.phased
```

and you can call it on this way:

```
#!/bin/bash
for chr in $(seq 1 29)
do
phase.sh chr_$chr
done
```

Comment: For robustness, see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable/27701642

Comment: @tripleee, it depend, as currently we control the variables quotes are overkill. if we talk about commands where you can get extra space in output or filenames with special characters will be OK.

Comment: We have way too many answers which simply assume people will not use real-world file names. Fixing them is usually easier than adding a caveat, and teaches people to use quoting properly.

Comment: @tripleee, this discussion go in direction of "The art of asking good questions" :)